# (New Linux User) elementaryOS installed smooth, but no internet -> STUCK

Tags: system-installation

First day of linux. (Trying to learn.)

Install was smooth, took 5 min of my time following directions. OS is beautiful and quick.

elementary OS 6 Odin
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Linux 5.11.0-41-generic

**No internet.** 5 hours of troubleshooting. no luck.

(built-in ethernet) Intel I219-V
(USB wifi adapter brand new) TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU
(USB wifi adapter old) NetGear A6100 AC600 [Realtek RTL8811AU]

1. Downloaded drivers from another computer and transferred with USB.

---> 2. Cannot use "make" command to install them.

------> 3. Tried to download make pkg and transfer with USB.

---------> 4. Cannot install "make" without using "dkms" command.

------------> 5. Cannot instal dkms pkg without an overwhelming number of dependencies...

Do other people run into these kinds of issues?
It seems like no driver and no common command is pre-installed.
(Nor are they easy to deliver to a machine with no internet access...)

I guess to some people there is a benefit to the barebones approach?

What do I do though? Thank you for any advice, I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly an unfortunate situation, but may not be too complicated if you have access to another computer that is running Elementary. This can also be done within a VM if your other machine is running a non-Linux OS.

In order to build the drivers on your machine, you will need to use `apt download` to get the `build-essential` packages required to compile them. This can be done in a Terminal like this:

```
sudo apt download <packages name here>
```

For you, the command would look like this:

```
sudo apt download build-essential make libc6-dev g++ gcc dpkg-dev libc
```

From here, you will need to copy the packages (`.deb` files) to a USB stick (or some other transportable media) and move them to the Elementary machine. To install them, you will do something like this:

```
sudo apt install <path to .deb file here>
```

Once the `build-essential` and other packages are installed, you should be able to compile the network driver(s) for your machine.

It's not often that a person has to jump through this many hoops when starting out with a modern Linux installation, but some hardware requires a little more effort at the start.